# Update script for SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I have a Blazor app that I used the following command to create the database.

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

The problem is the script generated is only good for a first time database with nothing in it.  Is there a command I can run to generate an update script?

Comment: Add migrations to your project

Comment: Q: How is Entity Framework supposed to work?  A: 1) Create a model.  2) Create a data context.  3) Add a migration (from MSVS: `Package Mgr Console > Add-Migration...`.  4) Update DB (from MSVS:  `Package Mgr Console > Update-Database...`).  As your schema evolves: 5) Perform subsequent Add-Migration/Update-Database.  STRONG SUGGESTION: do this from the MSVS IDE (vs. dotnet command line).

Comment: PS: Here's a good tutorial.  All the concepts are applicable to Blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

The whole migrations mechanism in EF is about keeping consistency between your data model and according db schema. Each time your data model changes you should generate new migration.

Think of migrations as of deltas, containing information of what was added and removed from particular tables in your database. It gets pretty clear if you look inside a generated migration class. There are EF related methods providing a layer of abstraction over SQL modifications on databse.
[Migrations overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)